# Get keyword from a (search engine) referrer url using PHP

Tags: php, url, preg-match, keyword

I am trying to get the search keyword from a referrer url. Currently, I am using the following code for Google urls. But sometimes it is not working...

```
$query_get = "(q|p)";
$referrer = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=learn+php+2&client=firefox";
preg_match('/[?&]'.$query_get.'=(.*?)[&]/',$referrer,$search_keyword);
```

Is there another/clean/working way to do this?

Thank you,
Prasad

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using PHP5 take a look at http://php.net/parse_url and http://php.net/parse_str

Example:

```
// The referrer
$referrer = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=learn+php+2&client=firefox';

// Parse the URL into an array
$parsed = parse_url( $referrer, PHP_URL_QUERY );

// Parse the query string into an array
parse_str( $parsed, $query );

// Output the result
echo $query['q'];
```

Comment: No problem, if your question is answered please click the check under the correct answer so everyone knows it's answered.

Comment: PHP_URL_QUERY does not work as the new "ajax'd" google uses a '#' to seperate the domain from the query string and not a '?'. So you get an empty array - a work around could be to find and replace the first instance of a '#' to a '?' in the url before processing

Answer (score 1):

There are different query strings on different search engines. After trying Wiliam's method, I have figured out my own method. (Because, Yahoo's is using 'p', but sometimes 'q')

```
$referrer = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=www.stack+overflow%2Ccom&ei=utf-8&fr=slv8-msgr&xargs=0&pstart=1&b=61&xa=nSFc5KjbV2gQCZejYJqWdQ--,1259335755";
$referrer_query = parse_url($referrer);
$referrer_query = $referrer_query['query'];
$q = "[q|p]"; //Yahoo uses both query strings, I am using switch() for each search engine
preg_match('/'.$q.'=(.*?)&/',$referrer,$keyword);
$keyword = urldecode($keyword[1]);
echo $keyword; //Outputs "www.stack overflow,com"
```

Thank you,
Prasad

Comment: In my example you could also check to see if the array key q or p were present, and if so use that instead of the other. To be honest, I recommend checking the domain it's coming from and working with the the data based off that. As of right now ANYONE coming from ANY site with "q" or "p" would look like it came from Google/Yahoo.

Comment: To prevent that, I am using this >>> if(preg_match('/[\.\/](google|yahoo|bing|geegain|mywebsearch|ask|alltheweb)\.[a-z\.]{2,5}[\/]/i',$referrer,$search_engine)){ <<<

Comment: pnm123 solution finds any element that is p= which could include cp= - which google url has, which will not result in the query string for the keywords.

Comment: @KB : You are correct. However I have modified the code and now it does not match those cp cq etc. HERE > [link](http://tinypaste.com/ff074)

Answer (score 1):

To supplement the other answers, note that the query string parameter that contains the search terms varies by search provider.   This snippet of PHP shows the correct parameter to use:

```
$search_engines = array(
    'q' => 'alltheweb|aol|ask|ask|bing|google',
    'p' => 'yahoo',
    'wd' => 'baidu',
    'text' => 'yandex'
);
```

Source: http://betterwp.net/wordpress-tips/get-search-keywords-from-referrer/

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
class GET_HOST_KEYWORD 
{ 
    public function get_host_and_keyword($_url) { 
        $p = $q = "";
        $chunk_url = parse_url($_url); 
        $_data["host"] = ($chunk_url['host'])?$chunk_url['host']:''; 
        parse_str($chunk_url['query']); 
        $_data["keyword"] = ($p)?$p:(($q)?$q:''); 
        return $_data; 
    } 
}     
// Sample Example 
$obj = new GET_HOST_KEYWORD(); 
print_r($obj->get_host_and_keyword('http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-&q=hire php php programmer')); 

// sample output
//Array
//(
//    [host] => www.google.co.in
//    [keyword] => hire php php programmer
//)

// $search_engines = array(
//    'q' => 'alltheweb|aol|ask|ask|bing|google',
//    'p' => 'yahoo',
//    'wd' => 'baidu',
//    'text' => 'yandex'
//);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = parse_url($request, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

Comment: Updated my post to add the second parameter. I was hoping he'd lookup the method to see how it works on his own but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work For Google, Bing and sometimes, Yahoo Search:

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
    $query = getSeQuery($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    echo $query;
} else {
    echo "I think they spelled REFERER wrong? Anyways, your browser says you don't have one.";
}



function getSeQuery($url = false) {
    $segments = parse_url($url);
    $keywords = null;
    if($query = isset($segments['query']) ? $segments['query'] : (isset($segments['fragment']) ? $segments['fragment'] : null)) {
    parse_str($query, $segments);
    $keywords = isset($segments['q']) ? $segments['q'] : (isset($segments['p']) ? $segments['p'] : null);
    }
    return $keywords;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe google and yahoo had updated their algorithm to exclude search keywords and other params in the url which cannot be received using http_referrer method.

Please let me know if above recommendations will still provide the search keywords.

What I am receiving now are below when using http referrer at my website end.

from google: https://www.google.co.in/
from yahoo: https://in.yahoo.com/

Ref: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/03/upcoming-changes-in-googles-http.html

Comment: The solutions above are not valid anymore. Google and Yahoo excluded the keywords from the referrer URL. You can not find the keyword anymore.